# How is passing a function as a parameter related to escaping autoclosure?

Tags: swift, escaping, inout, auto-close, mutating-function

```
struct MyStruct {
    var a = 0
    
    func foo() {
        print("Ok")
    }
    
    mutating func increase() {
        a += 1
    }
}

func runner(_ function: () -> Void) {
    function()
}

var myStruct = MyStruct()
runner(myStruct.foo) // Ok
runner(myStruct.increase)
//  Escaping autoclosure captures 'inout' parameter 'self'
```

Where is `autoclosure` here? And why is it escaping?

Comment: So what would be an answer that "suits you"? You already know it is impossible. What are you expecting?

Comment: Do you control `MyStruct` or do you only control `runner`? It *might* be possible if `increase` is declared in a different way.

Comment: I control runner, not MyStruct  But anyways it's interesting what do you mean  @Sweeper

Comment: My explanation wouldn't fit in a comment. If you want to know about that, edit the question to ask about that instead. Right now it is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Or, you can edit your question to *only* ask about "where is autoclosure here? And why is it escaping?"

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah, just was thinking exactly about that! Done ✅

Answer (score 0):

```
func runner(_ function: @autoclosure () -> Void) {
    function()
}

var myStruct = MyStruct()
runner(myStruct.foo()) // Ok
runner(myStruct.increase()) // ✅ Ok
```

Not ideal, but better than "impossible"

Comment: Syntactically this is basically the same as `runner { myStruct.increase() }` (which you explicitly rejected) but with `()` instead of `{}`...

Comment: Yea, you're right  @Sweeper